# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo after SDK update

Tags: java, android

I recently updated the Android 3.2 SDK, and ever since that i cannot run my application without it instantly force quitting and giving the "Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo" error. I have checked every post on the topic, and believe i have covered all the common issues which cause this error. I believe it might have something to do with the integrated google maps, however it was working properly before the update. Here is the LogCat, and manifest. the main activity class is quite large so i would like to avoid posting that.

```
05-16 14:08:16.313: I/dalvikvm(2880): Failed resolving 

Lcnp/apps/dronecontrol/DroneControlActivity; interface 112 'Lslickdevlabs/apps/usb2seriallib/AdapterConnectionListener;'
05-16 14:08:16.313: W/dalvikvm(2880): Link of class 'Lcnp/apps/dronecontrol/DroneControlActivity;' failed
05-16 14:08:16.313: D/AndroidRuntime(2880): Shutting down VM
05-16 14:08:16.313: W/dalvikvm(2880): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40239760)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{cnp.apps.dronecontrol/cnp.apps.dronecontrol.DroneControlActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cnp.apps.dronecontrol.DroneControlActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/cnp.apps.dronecontrol-2.apk]
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1739)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cnp.apps.dronecontrol.DroneControlActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/cnp.apps.dronecontrol-2.apk]
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:500)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1730)
05-16 14:08:16.313: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     ... 11 more
05-16 14:13:50.023: I/dalvikvm(2918): Failed resolving Lcnp/apps/dronecontrol/DroneControlActivity; interface 112 'Lslickdevlabs/apps/usb2seriallib/AdapterConnectionListener;'
05-16 14:13:50.023: W/dalvikvm(2918): Link of class 'Lcnp/apps/dronecontrol/DroneControlActivity;' failed
05-16 14:13:50.023: D/AndroidRuntime(2918): Shutting down VM
05-16 14:13:50.023: W/dalvikvm(2918): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40239760)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{cnp.apps.dronecontrol/cnp.apps.dronecontrol.DroneControlActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cnp.apps.dronecontrol.DroneControlActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/cnp.apps.dronecontrol-1.apk]
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1739)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cnp.apps.dronecontrol.DroneControlActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/cnp.apps.dronecontrol-1.apk]
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:500)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1730)
05-16 14:13:50.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2918):     ... 11 more
```

here is the manifest, i believe the error is in here, i did not change any code after i updated the SDK, it just started crashing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cnp.apps.dronecontrol"
    android:versionCode="7"
      android:versionName="1.6">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" android:required="true"></uses-feature>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity android:name=".DroneControlActivity"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MenuHelper"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 9):

The dreaded ClassNotFoundException.  You have to put your third party libraries in a "libs" folder and re-reference them (Right-click, properties, Java Build Path, Libraries, Add Jar...).

Comment: wow that fixed it, thank you so much, i would've never tried that, do you have an explanation why it worked before the update and not after?

Comment: @user1399328 because of the proguard version