# error- dalvik.system.PathClassLoader [data/app/com.my.appname-2.apk]

Tags: java, android

I searched a lot for similar kind of error, but I am not getting a solution for it. I am getting this error as soon as I start the app

```
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.airlife/com.example.airlife.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.airlife.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.airlife-2.apk]
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1785)
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.airlife.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.airlife-2.apk]
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1040)
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1777)
03-21 10:33:08.100: E/AndroidRuntime(13098):    ... 11 more
```

MainActivity.java is like this

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends MapActivity implements OnClickListener{

    private ImageButton mVid,mAgebtn,mWeightbtn,mPicbtn,mMsgbtn,mReqbtn,mHelibtn,mDocbtn,mContextbtn;

    private MapView mapView;

    private MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

          mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
          myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);

          mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
            mapView.postInvalidate();
            // call convenience method that zooms map on our location
            zoomToMyLocation();



        mAgebtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView36);
        mWeightbtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        mPicbtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        mMsgbtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        mReqbtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView32);
        mHelibtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnsearch);
        mDocbtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnprovide);
        mVid = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnpost);
        mContextbtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnsettings);


         mAgebtn.setOnClickListener(this);
         mWeightbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
         mPicbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
         mMsgbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
         mReqbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
         mHelibtn.setOnClickListener(this);
         mDocbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
         mVid.setOnClickListener(this);
         mContextbtn.setOnClickListener(this);


    }


     @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            // when our activity resumes, we want to register for location updates
            myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            // when our activity pauses, we want to remove listening for location updates
            myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
        }

        /**
         * This method zooms to the user's location with a zoom level of 10.
         */
        private void zoomToMyLocation() {
            GeoPoint myLocationGeoPoint = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
            if(myLocationGeoPoint != null) {
                mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocationGeoPoint);
                mapView.getController().setZoom(10);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot determine location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.airlife"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />



       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.airlife.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity android:name=".playvid" />
          <activity android:name=".Display" />
          <activity android:name=".Video" />
           <activity android:name=".Documents" />
                 <activity android:name=".Contact" />
                 <activity android:name=".FixedMyLocationOverlay" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please tell me why I am getting this error, and how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution. I had missed this code in my manifest file

```
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Class not found exception in MainActivity.

I think you've the wrong package, or that your APK doesn't have what you think it has.This is your package name.

```
com.example.airlife
```

Maku sure that it is imported in all activities as.

```
package com.example.airlife;
```

and don't forget to add entry in manifest file for every new activity.

If so, then make this change in manifest file. No need to mention your package name and remove allowBackUp

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I have added package com.example.airlife; in my MainActivity as well. I have not copied it here. I have made entries for all activities in manifest also.

Comment: no..now getting error as -Didn't find class "com.example.airlife.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.airlife-2.apk

Comment: Is it because I changed the target name of the project from Android 4.2 to Google APIs ?

Answer (score 0):

if not this try adding any library files you are using. missing library files may also cause this exception. see this link

[java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo after SDK update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624520/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo-after-s)

Comment: Is it because I changed the target name of the project from Android 4.2 to Google APIs ?