# Updated Eclipse and ADT not working with previously working packages.- Source not found

Tags: android, eclipse, path, adt

A previously working package and newer iterations have quit working for me since I was forced to update Eclipse and the ADT. The package is targeted at Android 10.

Previously, it imported without any complications. 
I tried a newer version and it no longer worked. At first I thought it was the newer program. Then I suspected it was the Eclipse + ADT install on my Debian machine. So I removed all Android packages (and reinstalled in various ways - Eclipse with the plugin and reinstalls of the ADT bundle in different places [purging all info in between each install]) and still it didn't work. I've also tried installing in OSX with the same problems - leading me to believe it's not an ADT install problem.

Quite often the packages will seem to compile without a problem - however, the start in the emulator crashes. [The emulators are all new AVMs as well.]

The console gives messages such as this:

```
05-29 16:17:13.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1385):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
```

In debugger the error message for a previously working (and unaltered project) returns -

```
The source is not found.
```

Is this related to some new ADT + Eclipse default settings? An update from Java 7 to Java 8?

The package will compile fine and I can manually install it on the AVM - something is failing in communication between the AVM, Eclipse, and the SDK.

```
05-31 09:38:43.025: W/dalvikvm(352): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/hardy/someapp/Someapp; (92)
05-31 09:38:43.025: W/dalvikvm(352): Link of class 'Lorg/hardy/someapp/Someapp;' failed
05-31 09:38:43.025: D/AndroidRuntime(352): Shutting down VM
05-31 09:38:43.025: W/dalvikvm(352): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-31 09:38:43.045: E/AndroidRuntime(352): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.hardy.monsterismus/org.hardy.someapp.Someapp}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hardy.someapp.Someapp in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.hardy.monsterismus-1.apk]
```

I believe it's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540378/error-dalvik-system-pathclassloader-data-app-com-my-appname-2-apk)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer.

The package installed fine - when I manually installed it from the sdk.
The problem was in communicating with the AVM through ADT.

This was the problem / not present in the manifest:

```
<uses-library
        android:name="org.hardy.someapp"/>
```

Adding it to the manifest seemed to fix it:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="Someapp"
        android:theme="@android:style/Animation" >
        <uses-library
        android:name="org.hardy.someapp"/>
        <activity android:name=".Someapp" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

I'm not sure how or why that happened.